# Basement Waterproofing Systems - Pros and Cons

Tags: waterproofing

**Background**

I am looking at providing my basement some form of waterproofing before I finish it. I currently have no water issues in it but would love the piece of mind before sealing everything up.  **My yard is graded correctly so all direct water goes away from house.** Like almost all houses there is natural moisture in the ground that collect around the house.

**Current System**

Currently my house has the front house wall and right house wall with corrugated tubing in the concrete, so it covers half of the outer wall. The back and left house walls have nothing.  I do notice a decent amount of calcium showing up in the sump basin which makes me believe some of the corrugated is punctured.

**Systems that I am aware of that exist**

My question really is from people's experiences what are the pros and cons of these methods?  More may exist which are better so feel free to add on as well.

1. Doing nothing - Cost = $0 - This is always the option for any project. If I had no problems before and sealed up the basement I should have no problems in the future as well. This does make me a bit nervous which is why I am asking the question.
2. On the tile vs on the side of the tile systems - Cost approximately $12,000 for 134 ft perimeter - Each contractor has given me their opinions of if it is better to be on the tile or off but of course they just promote their own systems.
3. Material choices - Most of the full systems will bust up the concrete at the perimeter, install a channel, patch back up with concrete. I have seen some companies use plastic and others metal for their channels. In my mind plastic won't rust but can crack, metal can rust in time but won't crack
4. Open vs Closed systems - The systems in which you have to bust up the concrete are considered closed systems as they all offer a "vapor lock barrier" of some kind to which a plastic or other material wall goes against the cinder blocks to help them drain into the underground system. Open systems such as (https://waterproof.com/) are systems you can install on the surface of the concrete with weep holes drilled into the cinder blocks so theoretically all leaks drip down the blocks, collect in the channel, and go into the sump hole. A system of this type is about $900 for my size basement which is considerably cheaper than the closed systems. They of course will not collect any surrounding soil moisture but is this really a problem?

Comment: As this is opinion based I will just leave a comment. I like keeping the outside dry by doing that nothing else matters. Perimeter drains with rock backfill are my choice as long as drainage is available. Trying to seal from the inside is a waste of $ in my opinion and inside drains allow water and humidity in the living space. If your area is dry with no evidence of moisture save the $ it may take 20 years before it leaks if ever so why fix something that is not broken. 20 years later it is possible the new drain you installed may get plugged up and need to be redone. Save and wait since dry.

Comment: How old is your house? Do you have neighbors that have had problems?

Comment: @Jack 60 years old. I am on the end of the neighborhood, next to an alley way. The neighbor on my one side has not had issues.

Comment: @EdBeal Thank you for the comments. I value your opinion highly in this SE on most things. What are your thoughts on material for the rock back fill systems? I do wonder if the metal ones have risk for corrosion over the years.  Both systems do have access panels so over the years a hose can be ran to clear out if any problems

Comment: I like river rock for back fill. I have seen slag iron used but I have not used it, I do know that the slag iron turns into a solid according to a friend, it drains but if you need to dig it up it almost needs a jackhammer. Yes if a access port is added and regular flushing the drain will last for ever with a good bed of rock or metal slag.

Comment: Eric, if you were to go with the system you linked in option 4, how would you finish the walls?

Comment: They would have to be offset that distance then. Framing would need to take that into account

Comment: I've considered adding a similar setup to the front wall in my basement, but can't afford to eat up 6 inches of space between the system and the framing as I also have a stair landing along that wall.

Comment: FWIW, there is a _lot_ of good advice on basement waterproofing on the net, starting with resources like This Old House.